# "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('" for stable repository set up

Tags: bash

While trying to [install docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository) on ubuntu 16.04 I am trying to set up the stable repository and get the following:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository \'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \$(lsb_release -cs) stable'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I am new to  Linux (today) so any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two things: don't post images of text, and two - remove backslash next to dollar sign.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I guess I need to use  "code" to illustrate my point?

Comment: no, you can use mouse to highlight text and Ctrl+Shift+C to copy it, and paste it here. After you paste, you can indent to four spaces for readability and formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

The `\` on the web page are to make the shell ignore the line breaks. If you put the whole command in one line you can just ignore them.

`'` and `"` have different meanings for the shell and you have to use `"` here.